# Add a list of names to a generated series

Tags: query, select, redshift, cross-join

I generated a date series this way:

```
SELECT generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2021-01-21', '1 day');
```

Additionally I have a list with name (Max Meyer, Anna Smith, Peter Gardner).
How could I add the name list to the date series, such that the name appears for every date in the series?

Comment: Redshift documentation says `generate_series` is not supported; does it actually work? If so, did you try the reportedly unsupported `values` command?

Comment: my bad, the generated series was used with postgresql. I am importing the date table (and name table) and need to use redshift within the tool, because redshift is not supported there

Comment: I can't say I understand your comment, but are you looking for `cross join`?

Comment: @wladi - I edited my answer if you're interested - I think that I"ve covered all possible options!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a [RedShift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) instance - now, [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-srf.html) isn't fully supported, but it appears to at least work [partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift)!

However, you are saying in comments that you are importing your date table into RedShift - so what I would do would be the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=834d54280ef8582ffda137da99ee5004)):

```
SELECT
  GENERATE_SERIES('2020-01-01'::DATE, '2020-01-15'::DATE, '1 DAY') AS dat;
```

Result (I reduced the date range to 15 days to make things legible - the same principle applies over a month, a year or even a decade...):

```
dat
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00
2020-01-03 00:00:00+00
2020-01-04 00:00:00+00
...
... snipped for brevity
...
15 rows
```

In PostgreSQL 9.6 - the oldest supported version at the time of writing - we can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  nom.dat, name.nam 
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES('2020-01-01'::DATE, '2020-01-15'::DATE, '1 DAY') AS nom (dat)
JOIN
  (VALUES  ('Max Meyer'), ('Anna Smith'), ('Peter Gardner')) AS name (nam) 
ON TRUE
ORDER BY  nom.dat, name.nam;
```

Result:

```
dat                     nam
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00  Anna Smith
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00  Max Meyer
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00  Peter Gardner
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00  Anna Smith
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00  Max Meyer
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00  Peter Gardner
...
... snipped for brevity
...
45 rows
```

So, what we have here is a `CROSS JOIN` between the `dat`s from the GENERATE_SERIES and the `nam`s in the the name table which we created using the `VALUES` clause. Effectively, I used the `ON TRUE` syntax which is the same as doing a `CROSS JOIN`.

Check out the `cross-join` tag [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-join/info):

> For any question involving a CROSS JOIN, i.e. combining every
> SELECT-ed field from one table with every SELECT-ed field from
> another.

From [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-table-expressions.html), we have:

> FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2 is equivalent to FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON TRUE (see below). It is also equivalent to FROM T1, T2.

So, we have our 15 date fields `CROSS JOIN`-ed with our 3 names = 45 records in our resultset!

Now, if you've already created the `dates` table (see the fiddle) and you are simply importing it, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT d.dat, name.nam  FROM
dates d                   -- <<== imported date (from GENERATE_SERIES) table!
JOIN
  (VALUES  ('Max Meyer'), ('Anna Smith'), ('Peter Gardner')) AS name(nam) 
ON TRUE
ORDER BY d.dat, name.nam;
```

Result:

```
Same as for the CROSS JOIN above.
```

I've left a couple of alternative syntaxes/solutions using `CROSS JOIN` at the bottom of the fiddle - they may or may not be of interest to you.

Finally - from version [8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/queries-with.html), you **may** be able to use a CTE.

```
WITH name AS
(
  SELECT 'Max Meyer' AS nam
  UNION
  SELECT 'Anna Smith'
  UNION 
  SELECT 'Peter Gardner'
)
    SELECT d.dat, name.nam  FROM
    dates d                   -- <<== imported date (from GENERATE_SERIES) table!
    CROSS JOIN name.nam
```

which should give the same result (untested). If CTE's don't work on Redshift, you could just `JOIN` to the table of `SELECT`s with `UNION`s... as a subquery. Thanks to @mustaccio for pointing out that "VALUES list used as constant tables..." isn't supported by Redshift.

Comment: [Unsupported PostgreSQL features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html): VALUES list used as constant tables...

Comment: @mustaccio - Nuts! Wouldn't life be great if every server had PostgreSQL syntax? :-) However, if you check the fiddle, you'll see that there's more than one way to skin a cat! :-)  There's  the `SELECT 'blah' AS nam UNION...` - does that do the trick?

Comment: @mustaccio - I've dealt with your point about `VALUES list used as constant tables...` not being supported - thanks for pointing that out!